# create table with Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm pretty new with react and web dev in general.

I've written down this code but it doesn't work like I intended (*classic*)

```
 return (
 
 <div>
 
        <table className="table table-stripped">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Profit in KRW</th>
                                <th>Profit %</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        
                        {Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                        return (
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>{key}</td>
                                     <td>{value['profit_krw']}</td>
                                     <td>{value['profit_perc']}</td>
                                 </tr>
                                );
                         })}
                        
                </tbody>
        </table>
     
</div>

)
```

Here `data` looks like `{'ada':{'profit_krw': '5000', 'profit_perc': '0.2'}, 'btc': {'profit_krw': '10000', 'profit_perc': '0.4'}}`

So in the end I would like it to look like ideally,

```
Name       Profit in KRW        Profit%
   ada             5000               0.2
   btc            10000               0.4
```

Comment: what is the output that its giving ?

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything so you would need to make an array then push onto that array in the loop or you can use a map instead of foreach

Comment: currently just the heading and not the data

Comment: would it look like this .map((key, value) => ? @ColinHale

Comment: I added an answer to help shown how it would look.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach doesn't return anything so you will need to use a map there or you will need to push onto an array. I would recommend the map:

```
   <tbody> 
    {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
       return (
           <tr>
             <td>{key}</td>
             <td>{value['profit_krw']}</td>
             <td>{value['profit_perc']}</td>
           </tr>
          );
        })}
   </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to return something you can use `map()` because `forEach()` doesn't return anything

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

---

```
export default function App() {
  const data = {
    ada: { profit_krw: "5000", profit_perc: "0.2" },
    btc: { profit_krw: "10000", profit_perc: "0.4" }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Profit in KRW</th>
            <th>Profit %</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{key}</td>
                <td>{value["profit_krw"]}</td>
                <td>{value["profit_perc"]}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```